# Safari handling CSS3 Transforms unacceptably

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, transform

I just found out that on my website http://lju.me that Safari is handling the CSS3 transforms in a completely different fashion than Chrome is.  The main gist of the way that the site behaves is that I have an outer div called "warp" surrounding four inner divs like so

```
<div id="warp">
    <div id="one" class="slice"></div>
    <div id="two" class="slice"></div>
    <div id="three" class="slice"></div>
    <div id="four" class="slice"></div>
</div>
```

Let's say the first inner div gets clicked.  Then I apply the class .goOne to #warp

```
#warp.goOne {
    // floating, positioning and transition code here
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(4);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(4);
    transform: scaleX(4);
}

#warp.goOne div{
    // floating, positioning and transition code here
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(.25);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(.25);
    transform: scaleX(.25);
}
```

basically, the main idea is at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qwdM4/ (although I hear the distortion is not as bad there (I don't have safari, so I can't tell)).  Could you guys give me any insight on why this works totally fine on Chrome but not on Safari?